# JAI codec PNGImageEncoder throws division by zero exception

Tags: java, jai

My company has an EJB that attempts to convert a grayscale TIFF image (which is read into a `RenderedImage`) to a PNG image through `PNGImageEncoder.encode`.

Today, I learned that it would, under circumstances that I don't know (I was not the author, and I am not present on the test site), throw a division by zero exception. I found it unusual that it was thrown by `PNGImageEncoder`. Trying to search for the issue online did not turn in anything useful.

The exception:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGImageEncoder.encodePass(PNGImageEncoder.java:367)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGImageEncoder.writeIDAT(PNGImageEncoder.java:476)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGImageEncoder.encode(PNGImageEncoder.java:1026)
    at com.nameOfMyCompany.SomeProgram.writePNG(SomeProgram.java:555)
```

Upon further investigation, I suspect that the TIFF images used (which I have no access to) have the bit depth set to 0 for some reason ([ImageEncoder code](https://github.com/jefferis/ij-plugins/blob/master/Sun_JAI_Sample_IO_Source_Code_v_1_1_1/src/non_com/media/jai/codec/PNGImageEncoder.java)). `PNGImageEncoder.encodePass` cannot calculate `samplesPerByte`, and the exception is thrown.

My question: Am I right in suspecting the TIFF images to be the reason? What else could cause the above exception?

Comment: This is my first post in StackExchange (although I've lurked here for quite a while). The formatting of my question may not fit the site well enough; sorry if that is the case.

Comment: TIFF is a pretty old format, and through the years its specifications and required/optional tags have inflated beyond belief. It is possible there is a combination of basic properties tags that make it "valid" for other software but not for the library that you use to read it (which one?). Best is to get your hands on the original TIFF file, then, so you can investigate the root cause.

Comment: @rad-lexus The `RenderedImage` was created by `com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage`. Further findings by my coworker suggested that it's not the problems of the TIFF files and Java code at all. I've since moved on to work on other things, but I may update this if the cause can be pinpointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is yes/no so the answer is yes since the line there shows a division that means there is a division and probably by zero if the error says so.

Beyond that you say "(which is read into a RenderedImage)": is this displayable in java (can you create a jpanel and show this RenderedImage?)? if so then you can use some other mechanism (ImageIO) to convert the Renderable to png (and skip this program that you are using). If not then the long process of TIFF investigation starts.